# pymysql - pymysql.err.InternalError: 1054, user input string used as column name

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am new to Python and MySQL so I am practicing with a readonly account. I am trying to create an executable script that basically asks for a first name, last name, then inserts them into the query and returns the results. Below is what I have and the error I get:

```
cur = conn.cursor()

user_input_fname = raw_input("Enter Trainer First Name: ")
user_input_lname = raw_input("Enter Trainer Last Name: ")

cur.execute(" SELECT concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS clientName, us.sessionid AS sessionID, convert_tz(s.starttime, '+00:00', '+04:00') AS sessionTimeEST, concat(t.firstname, ' ', t.lastname) AS trainerName FROM usersessions us LEFT JOIN users u ON us.userid = u.id INNER JOIN sessions s ON us.sessionid = s.id INNER JOIN trainers t ON s.trainerid = t.id WHERE u.firstname = %s AND u.lastname =%s  ORDER BY s.starttime;' " %(user_input_fname, user_input_lname))

data = cur.fetchall()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

> ERROR: pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'ethan' in
>   'where clause'")

I feel like it's a ' or " missing somewhere but I can't figure out my syntactical mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string literals within sql must be enclosed by `'` or `"`. You are providing names in the `where` clause, so those should be enclosed by one of the speechmarks:

```
...WHERE u.firstname = '%s' AND u.lastname ='%s'...
```

There is also a trailing single quote just before the end of the sql statement. If that's truly in your code, then it must be removed.

Comment: Thank you, I did miss that ' and did not have them enclosed. I tried to enclose the strings but still got the error, which was probably the trailing '. I also didn't have a print and assumed fetchall would print.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended use string interpolation (i.e. the `%` operator) to put those values into the query, at it can lead to SQL injection attacks (depending on where your data comes from).

It's safer (and also fixes your quoting issue) if you pass in those arguments to the execute method.

I.e. instead call something like:

```
cur.execute("""
SELECT concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS clientName, us.sessionid AS sessionID, convert_tz(s.starttime, '+00:00', '+04:00') AS sessionTimeEST, concat(t.firstname, ' ', t.lastname) AS trainerName
FROM usersessions us LEFT JOIN users u ON us.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN sessions s ON us.sessionid = s.id
INNER JOIN trainers t ON s.trainerid = t.id
WHERE u.firstname = %s AND u.lastname =%s
ORDER BY s.starttime;
""", (user_input_fname, user_input_lname))
```

This then lets the MySQL library safely quote your input as it sees fit.